# I want to create Photo Filters by Javascript

Tags: imagefilter

Before upload a photo to my server I want to modify background, layout,.. of image like as Photo Filter of Instagram (please review attach image).

[image: Photo Filters of Instagram]

Please help me about that, jQuery plugin or Library to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For styling images, you should mostly use `CSS`. There are pretty good `CSS` libraries out there for this. for example [Instagram.css](https://github.com/picturepan2/instagram.css)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="instagram.min.css">
```

Add a class `filter-[filter-name]` from list of possible classes:

```html
<figure class="filter-[filter-name]">
  <img src="assets/img/instagram.jpg">
</figure>
```

Results:
[image: Instagram.css filters]

You can then use javascript or jQuery to dynamically add classes and apply filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solution for your problem
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/#toc-conclusion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL